# PHP Order Array by Key Value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I know this has been posted before, but I couldnt get it to work for me :s not sure why! But anywhooo My array $servers looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dell PowerEdge R210 II
            [1] => 8
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 8
                    [1] => Sock
                    [2] => Price
                    [3] => ImageURL
                    [4] => CPU
                    [5] => Memory
                    [6] => HDD
                    [7] => Bandwidth
                    [8] => OS
                    [9] => Upgrades
                    [10] => OrderLink
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dell PowerEdge R210 II 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => Sock
                    [2] => Price
                    [3] => ImageURL
                    [4] => CPU
                    [5] => Memory
                    [6] => HDD
                    [7] => Bandwidth
                    [8] => OS
                    [9] => Upgrades
                    [10] => OrderLink
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dell PowerEdge R210 II 3
            [1] => 3
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => Sock
                    [2] => Price
                    [3] => ImageURL
                    [4] => CPU
                    [5] => Memory
                    [6] => HDD
                    [7] => Bandwidth
                    [8] => OS
                    [9] => Upgrades
                    [10] => OrderLink
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dell PowerEdge R210 II 4
            [1] => 4
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => Sock
                    [2] => Price
                    [3] => ImageURL
                    [4] => CPU
                    [5] => Memory
                    [6] => HDD
                    [7] => Bandwidth
                    [8] => OS
                    [9] => Upgrades
                    [10] => OrderLink
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dell PowerEdge R210 II 5
            [1] => 5
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => Sock
                    [2] => Price
                    [3] => ImageURL
                    [4] => CPU
                    [5] => Memory
                    [6] => HDD
                    [7] => Bandwidth
                    [8] => OS
                    [9] => Upgrades
                    [10] => OrderLink
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dell PowerEdge R210 II 6
            [1] => 6
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6
                    [1] => Sock
                    [2] => Price
                    [3] => ImageURL
                    [4] => CPU
                    [5] => Memory
                    [6] => HDD
                    [7] => Bandwidth
                    [8] => OS
                    [9] => Upgrades
                    [10] => OrderLink
                )

        )

)
```

I'd like to have the array re-arranged and put back into $servers but in order of $servers[x][1]

So where the singular number is (1st object is 8) I'd like it to sort it with the smallest number 1st, moving to the largest!

Many thanks

ps i tried this

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($servers, "cmp");
?>
```

but it didnt seem to work!

Thanks

Comment: Read up on [PHP multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php). There are some good examples on the manual too.

Comment: Your `cmp` function needs to check the values of the `$a[1]` vs. `$b[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cmp` is wrong. `$a` and `$b` are arrays like

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Dell PowerEdge R210 II 6
        [1] => 6
        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 6
                [1] => Sock
                [2] => Price
                [3] => ImageURL
                [4] => CPU
                [5] => Memory
                [6] => HDD
                [7] => Bandwidth
                [8] => OS
                [9] => Upgrades
                [10] => OrderLink
            )

    )
```

and you must compare `$a[1]` with `$b[1]`:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a[1] - $b[1];
}
```